# Order by or Max in EF In-Memory Database

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core

Is it possible that the order by datetime or the get max() datetime is not working in the in-memory database?

```
var document =  dbContext.Documents
.Where(x => x.CompanyGuid == companyGuid && x.PackageDocuments.Where(y => y.PackageGuid == packageGuid).Count() > 0)
.OrderByDescending(x => x.KeepDocumentUntilDateUtc)
.FirstOrDefault();
```

It always returns me the first value of the list and not the record with the max datetime

Comment: Of course it is easy to test this. When you tried debugging with an extra `ToList()` or `AsEnumerable()` just before `OrderByDescending`, did this render the same unexpected data?

Comment: yes same result with this 
                var document =  dbContext.Documents
                    .Where(x => x.CompanyGuid == companyGuid && x.PackageDocuments.Where(y => y.PackageGuid == packageGuid).Count() > 0)
                    .ToList()
                    .OrderByDescending(x => x.KeepDocumentUntilDateUtc)
                    .FirstOrDefault();

Comment: Well: there you know! As the data was fetched from the database before you OrderBy, you can be certain that the problem is not caused by the in-memory database. Next step:  fill a local List with the same or similar data and then do the OrderByDescending.

Comment: thanks for the hint. it was a error in my testing code.